# column-break-inside: avoid is not working on iOS

Tags: css

I have a J5 mod_articles_category which appears in a sidebar on large screens and drops to full width on smaller screens. I have added CSS so that when it's full width it appears as three, then ten columns, rather than one. Each li element has a bottom border, bottom box shadow and bottom margin. On Windows and my Android phone it displays correctly, but on my iPad in portrait mode it doesn't: [image: screenshot]

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: #e6edce;
  }
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  }
.three-cols {
  columns: 3 200px;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}
li {
border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0 #ffffff;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
</style>

<div>
<ul class="three-cols">
  <li><a href="/news-and-events/centenary/the-1920s">The 1920s</a>  </li>
  <li><a href="/news-and-events/centenary/the-1930s">The 1930s</a>  </li>
  <li><a href="/news-and-events/centenary/the-1940s">The 1940s</a>  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What do I need to do to put this right?